# How to declare an entity contain another entity in typeorm?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I want to declare an entity contain another entity in typeorm, so I can re-use base entity or focus on certain columns, is this possible? like this:

```
export class Base {//can be re-use
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @CreateDateColumn()
    created_at: Date;

    @UpdateDateColumn()
    updated_at: Date;
}

@Entity('person')//for insert/update/select
@Index(['first_name', 'last_name'], { unique: true })
export class PersonData {
    @Column()
    first_name: string;

    @Column()
    last_name: string;
}


@Entity('person')//for create table
export class Person {
    Base
    PersonData
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TypeORM permits you to extend entity classes](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/entities.md#entity-inheritance).

You can declare your classes as follows:

```
export class Base {//can be re-use
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @CreateDateColumn()
    created_at: Date;

    @UpdateDateColumn()
    updated_at: Date;
}

@Entity('person')//for insert/update/select
@Index(['first_name', 'last_name'], { unique: true })
export class Person extends Base {
    @Column()
    first_name: string;

    @Column()
    last_name: string;
}
```

And re-use the `Base` class elsewhere:

```
@Entity('someotherentity')
export class SomeOtherEntity extends Base {
    // extra columns here ...
}
```